# Class instance memory address in constructor C++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, constructor, memory-address

I have a struct that gets initialized in a class constructor, and I need the struct to have a pointer with the memory address of the class that initialized it so that when I call the struct's callback, it can send the instance of the class it has as a parameter.

Here is some code:

```
struct TouchZone {

    int Layer;
    bool Active = false;
private:
    int Width;
    int Height;
    int X;
    int Y;
    Button *linkedButton;
    void(*Callback)(Button &sender);

public:
    TouchZone()
    {

    }

    TouchZone(int width, int height, int x, int y, void((*callback)(Button &sender)), int lyr = 100)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Active = true;
        Callback = callback;
        Layer = lyr;
}

    Button* getLinkedButton() {
        return linkedButton;
    }

    void resize(int width, int height, int x, int y, int lyr = -1) {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        if (lyr != -1)
        {
            Layer = lyr;
        }
    }

    void UseCallback() {
        Callback(*linkedButton);
    }

    int getX() {
        return X;
    }

    int getSpanX() {
        return X + Width;
    }

    int getY() {
        return Y;
    }

    int getSpanY() {
        return Y + Height;
    }

    bool CheckBounds(int tX, int tY) {
        if (((tX >= this->X) && (tX <= this->getSpanX())) && ((tY >= this->Y) && (tY <= this->getSpanY()))) {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    void SetLinkedButton(Button *butt) {
        linkedButton = butt;
    }

};

class Button {
public:
    int Color;
    int layer;
    Outline outline;
    RectType rectType;
    int getSpanX();
    int getSpanY();
    int getX();
    int getY();
    bool isEnabled();
    bool PressChecking = false;
    void enable();
    void disable();
    void draw();
    void resize(int ix, int iy, int isx, int isy);
    Button();
    Button(int ix, int iy, int isx, int isy, int color, void(*callback)(Button& sender), RectType bt, Outline ot, bool pressCheck);
    static void FindButtonPressed(int x, int y);
    TouchZone theZone;
private:
    String Text;
    static LinkedList<TouchZone> YaBoisTouches;
    int X, Y, SizeX, SizeY;

};
int Button::getSpanX() {
    return (this->X + this->SizeX);
    }
int Button::getSpanY() {
    return (this->Y + this->SizeY);
}
int Button::getX()
{
    return this->X;
}
int Button::getY()
{
    return this->Y;
}
Button::Button() {

}
Button::Button(int ix, int iy, int isx, int isy, int color, void(*callback)(Button &sender), RectType bt, Outline ot, bool pressCheck){
    this->X = ix; this->Y = iy; this->SizeX = isx; this->SizeY = isy; this->outline = ot; this->rectType = bt; this->Color = color; this->PressChecking = pressCheck;
    this->draw();

    theZone = TouchZone(this->SizeX, this->SizeY, this->X, this->Y, callback);
    theZone.SetLinkedButton(this); //This is where I try to pass the specific instance of this class to the struct.
    Button::YaBoisTouches.add(theZone);
}
void Button::resize(int ix, int iy, int isx, int isy) {
    this->X = ix; this->Y = iy; this->SizeX = isx; this->SizeY = isy;
    theZone.resize(this->SizeX, this->SizeY, this->X, this->Y);
    this->draw();
}
void Button::FindButtonPressed(int x, int y) {
    TouchZone FoundZone;
    int HighestLayer = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Button::YaBoisTouches.size(); i++)
    {
        if (Button::YaBoisTouches.get(i).CheckBounds(x, y)) {
            if (Button::YaBoisTouches.get(i).Layer > HighestLayer) {
                HighestLayer = YaBoisTouches.get(i).Layer;
                FoundZone = YaBoisTouches.get(i);
            }
        }
    }
    if (FoundZone.Active) {
        if (FoundZone.getLinkedButton()->PressChecking) {
            if (!pressed) { FoundZone.UseCallback(); }
        }
        else {
            FoundZone.UseCallback();
        }
    }
}
```

In the constructor of the `Button` class I'm creating a `TouchZone` struct. In the struct I'm trying to store a pointer to the specific instance of the `Button` class that created that `TouchZone`. I can not figure out how to correctly do this inside of the constructor, nor do I know if it's possible. What I have here compiles, but my lack of knowledge with pointers and memory addresses seems to give me results I don't want.

This is an example function of how I intend to use the `Button` class's reference to a callback.

```
void HomeScreen(Button& sender) {
    Serial.println(sender.getSpanX()); //Prints some number like 2133411092 but varies every time. Should be 200.
    Serial.println(sender.theZone.getSpanX()); //Constantly prints 85, but should also be 200.
    sender.disable();
    theScreen.fillScr(VGA_MAROON);
    delay(300);
    theScreen.fillScr(VGA_WHITE);
    Serial.println(sender.getX()); //Usually prints some number like -149863422 but varies every time
    sender.resize(sender.getX(), 10, sender.getSpanX(), sender.getSpanY()); //The button disappears on the screen, which it should not.
    sender.enable();

}
```

This question is my first, and I think it might be too bloated. Just to recap, my goal is to pass a class instance reference to a struct *inside* of the class's constructor.

Answer (score 1):

`this` pointer is created after constructor call is completed.

> pointer is created only after constructor call is completed. You cannot use class pointer before constructor call is completed. – [miradham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4265714/miradham)

Comment: Well my comment was not answer... and you have to check usage for your specific case more detaily.

Comment: The `this` pointer is valid in the constructor. You cannot *use* it much as the object is not yet fully constructed, but you *can* store it and use it later.

Comment: @BoPersson Am I not doing that when I pass the pointer to the TouchZone struct? I'm not using the pointer until the button is actually constructed and visible on the UI I'm interfacing with.

Comment: Passing the pointer is ok. Storing the pointer is also ok. Using it to access parts of the pointed-to object is (at least) dangerous until the constructor is completed. Using it later is fine.

Comment: @BoPersson Okay, thanks for the insight. I must be screwing something up somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Either pass a pointer to the `Button` to the constructor for the `theZone`, or add a `setLinkedButton` class to `TouchZone`, and call that in the body of the `Button` constructor.